# Which DHCP clients use which options?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, unix, dhcp, dhcp-option

I would like to use my DHCP server to give information about some local services like ntp, using DHCP options as explained in the dhcp-options(5) manpage.

Does anyone here know, or is there a good document on the net, which options I can reasonably expect clients on different operating systems to know about? I imagine that things like "option font-servers" will be ignored by Windows and Mac DCHP clients because their host OS's don't use X11 fonts, but how about ntp-servers, smtp-server, subnet-mask or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this file:
[IPConfiguration.xml](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/bootp/bootp-133/IPConfiguration.bproj/IPConfiguration.xml)

Which is found in:

/System/Library/SystemConfiguration/IPConfiguration.bundle/Contents/Resources/IPConfiguration.xml

It has an array which lists the DHCP options that Mac OS X requests. Whether or not it can request others, I don't know...

Comment: This file is not present in OSX 10.9.4 - anyone know how to do this in this version of OSX?

Answer (score 0):

Use a network sniffer like `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to see which options are requested by your clients.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I asked if there's any existing knowledge because I wanted to avoid testing this for n DHCP servers across m different clients...